# does ktor support multiple sslConnector config for individual domain along with specific ssl certificate

Tags: ktor

I want to use Ktor to serve two domains, with individual ssl certificate, below is my configuration to do :

```kotlin
val environment = applicationEngineEnvironment {
    val pwdCharArray = "password1".toCharArray()
    val kstFile = File("perkey/site1.jks")
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS").apply { load(kstFile.inputStream(), pwdCharArray) }
    sslConnector(
        keyStore = keyStore,
        keyAlias = "site1",
        keyStorePassword = { pwdCharArray },
        privateKeyPassword = { pwdCharArray }
    ) {
        host = "site1.domain.com"
        port = 3443
        keyStorePath = kstFile
    }

    val pwdCharArray2 = "site2".toCharArray()
    val kstFile2 = File("perkey/site2.jks")
    val keyStore2 = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS").apply { load(kstFile2.inputStream(), pwdCharArray2) }
    sslConnector(
        keyStore = keyStore2,
        keyAlias = "site2",
        keyStorePassword = { pwdCharArray2 },
        privateKeyPassword = { pwdCharArray2 }
    ) {
        host = "site2.domain.com"
        port = 443
        keyStorePath = kstFile2
    }

    module(Application::module)
}
embeddedServer(Tomcat, environment).start(wait = true)
```

after `./gradlew run` I saw the log:

```
2022-12-19 22:46:28 INFO Responding at https://site1.domain.com:3443
2022-12-19 22:46:28 INFO Responding at https://site2.domain.com:443
```

but I can only visit the site2.domain.com that used the default port of ssl, when I try to visit https://site1.domain.com:3443 it took long time and end up response time out error.

I use **netstat** to ensure the 3443 port is listening.

```
root@VM-4-10-ubuntu:~# netstat -anp | grep 443
tcp6       0      0 :::3443                 :::*                    LISTEN      164500/java         
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      164500/java
```

both domains can reach my server, I have test by keep only one sslConnector config and have the port set to 443.

so does Ktor support this?

of source I can use reverse proxy such as Nginx to do this, just seeking whether Ktor can do this or not

Comment: Could you please tell me does making requests to IP-addresses instead of domains work?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman no, still can't reach by ip address

Comment: I've tested a local setup with multiple SSL connectors and was able to make requests to all defined ports, although the certificate validation was disabled due to self-signed certificates. Are you able to reproduce this problem locally? Does a client successfully make an HTTPS request with disabled certificate validation?